# SQL UPDATE with COALESCE and PARTITION BY statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update NULL column values with values from the same column that are from the same Item and DateAdded:

Before:

| DateAdded | Item | SalePrice | SaleDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/02/2024 | Apple | 99 | 1/12/2024 |
| 1/02/2024 | Apple | NULL | NULL |
| 2/05/2024 | Apple | 102 | 2/12/2024 |
| 2/05/2024 | Apple | NULL | NULL |
| 2/05/2024 | Banana | NULL | NULL |
| 2/05/2024 | Banana | 101 | 2/13/2024 |
| 2/05/2024 | Banana | NULL | NULL |
| 2/06/2024 | Banana | NULL | NULL |

After:

| DateAdded | Item | SalePrice | SaleDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/02/2024 | Apple | 99 | 1/12/2024 |
| 1/02/2024 | Apple | **99** | **1/12/2024** |
| 2/05/2024 | Apple | 102 | 2/12/2024 |
| 2/05/2024 | Apple | **102** | **2/12/2024** |
| 2/05/2024 | Banana | **101** | **2/13/2024** |
| 2/05/2024 | Banana | 101 | 2/13/2024 |
| 2/05/2024 | Banana | **101** | **2/13/2024** |
| 2/06/2024 | Banana | NULL | NULL |

I get the following error with the below code:

```
UPDATE table1
SET SaleDate = ISNULL(SaleDate, COALESCE(SaleDate, MAX(SaleDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Item, CAST([DateAdded] AS DATE)))
   ,SalePrice = ISNULL(SalePrice, COALESCE(SalePrice, MAX(SalePrice) OVER (PARTITION BY Item, CAST([DateAdded] AS DATE)))
WHERE CAST(DateAdded AS DATE) > '2024-01-01'
```

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to set value to previous max value if it's NULL. There is probably a whole bunch of answers, but the key is to use a subquery because you can't use window functions in update directly. Also, `ISNULL(SaleDate, coalesce(SaleDate` makes no sense, it's enough do: `ISNULL(SaleDate, ...` without COALESCE

Comment: The error is clear - you can only use windowing functions in `SELECT`. You'll have to use a subquery. Why is `CAST(DateAdded  AS DATE) ` used at all though? This can be a serious problem. If the field uses one of the date types the cast will result in bad statistic estimation. If it's text, it's a bigger problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data as DDL+DML statements and desired output after the update.

Comment: @shawnt00 that would be extremely ineffective

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
DateAdded is a datetime, and I wanted to partition by only the same day date, not the exact datetime. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: But it would be *slower* @shawnt00 ; it would likely result in 2 scans (but hopefully seeks) on the other table. You state *"I don't use joins on updates."* but *why not*? Use the tools available to you, and write performant queries. Don't use a hammer to put a screw in the wall because that's the tool you already had in your hand; get the appropriate screwdriver from your toolbox.

Comment: @ThomA because it was always buggy and I admittedly forget that ctes are updateable. (That comment was along with my answer. I tend to favor standard SQL when possible.) The optimizer has always handled those pretty well and so don't know what "pretty ineffective" implies exactly. I'm just exhausted. The answer four votes and I can barely get a reply for OP on clarification. It's time to move on.

Comment: Buggy? I can't say I've ever encountered such a bug, @shawnt00 , do you have any (recent) citations it's buggy?

Comment: One to many joins used to cause a situation where the row could be updated multiple times and the final value would stick. Granted the CTE approach is clean but we don't even know whether this is just a one-off query or something run regularly. The concerns about scans often irrelevant. I'm tired of wasting my time having to satisfy everybody while getting little positive feedback on any front. Software devs need to work on their EQ.

Comment: Why do you sometimes use `ISNULL` and sometimes use `COALESCE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As clearly shown in the error message, you can't use window functions directly in an `UPDATE`, you need a subquery.

But you can update the subquery directly, no need to join.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      NewSaleDate  = ISNULL(SaleDate,  max(SaleDate)  over (partition by Item, CAST(DateAdded AS DATE)),
      NewSalePrice = ISNULL(SalePrice, max(SalePrice) over (partition by Item, CAST(DateAdded AS DATE))
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE DateAdded >= CAST('20240102' AS datetime)
)
UPDATE cte
SET SaleDate  = NewSaleDate,
    SalePrice = NewSalePrice
WHERE (SaleDate IS NULL OR SalePrice IS NULL);
```

In SQL Server 2022+ and Azure, it may be better to use `DATETRUNC(day, DateAdded)` rather than casting.

Comment: `DateAdded` is a `datetime`, and I wanted to partition by only the same day date, not the exact datetime. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No that's fine, but then the `WHERE` doesn't need a `CAST`